# combine data frames of different lists in a single list

Tags: r

I have two (or more) lists of the same number of data frames and want to combine my data frames of the different lists in a single list. So as an output I want to get a single list of the same number of data frames as in each individual list.

Sounds a bit complicated, but basically I want to do this in an expandable and easier way:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4))
l1 <- list(d1,d2)
d3 <- data.frame(y1=c(11,22,33),y2=c(44,55,66))
d4 <- data.frame(y1=c(33,22,11),y2=c(66,55,44))
l2 <- list(d3,d4)

new_d1 <- do.call(rbind,list(l1[[1]],l2[[1]]))
new_d2 <- do.call(rbind,list(l1[[2]],l2[[2]]))
output <- list(new_d1,new_d2)
```

The output should than look like this:

```
> output
[[1]]
y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
4 11 44
5 22 55
6 33 66

[[2]]
y1 y2
1  3  6
2  2  5
3  1  4
4 33 66
5 22 55
6 11 44
```

Additionally, which function can I use if l1 and l2 are already sitting in a list themselves?

I already looked at `lapply()` and `sapply()`, but both functions don't really fit. In the forums I only find solutions to combine a list of data frames in a single data frame.

Comment: `Map(rbind, l1, l2)`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Please post it as an asnwer and close this.

Comment: I'll leave it to you, @akrun. Feel free to undelete your answer - I don't mind if you add the `Map`. I believe it's a duplicate anyway

Comment: then, please dupe it.  I can't use google to find a dupe as I have restrictions in work

Comment: That's funny. You're asking me to dupe a question :-) What happened to the fastest gun in the world?

Comment: Could I extend my question plz? I actually simplified my problem a little bit too much..
What if l1 and l2 are already in a list, can I then use Map(rbind...) within lapply() ?!

Comment: If it is more complicated, you should update your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simple case of `l1` and `l2` being lists in the global environment, you can use

```
Map(rbind, l1, l2)
```

For the other case, when `l1` and `l2` are already sitting in a `list`, you can use

```
l <- list(l1, l2)
Reduce(function(...) Map(rbind, ...), l)
```